# Mvc Jquery Ajax Post returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to post two parameteres...
This is the ajax code

```
function Kaydet() {
        var params = {};
        var Kiralayan = $("#RentForm").serialize();            
        params.kisi = Kiralayan ;
        params.aracid = P.AracID;           
        console.log(params);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Save","AracKirala")',
            data: params,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != "OK") {
                    alert("Kayıt yapılamadı.");
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("RentForm").reset();
                    alert("Kayıt başarıyla gerçekleştirildi.");
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    Ara();
                }

            }
        });
```

Method

```
public ActionResult Save(Kiralayan kisi = null, int aracid = 0)
    {
```

the problem is ajax posts "aracid" corretly but "kisi" turns null when the method is trigged...
I tried not to post "aracid" with "kisi" so ajax posted well for one parameter "kisi", but doesnt work together...

Comment: Seems weird that you are serializing an entire form into one variable.  Did you look to see what is being sent up in the Ajax request in the network tab of the console?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you chose the *later* of two near-identical answers and only chose to comment on the other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you serializing the form, then you can add additional values to it with the `.param()` function

```
var data = $("#RentForm").serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'aracid': AracID }, true);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Save","AracKirala")',
    data: data,
    ....
```

Comment: shouldn't he change contoller as well? I mean add `aracid` property to model?

Comment: No. On its own `$("#RentForm").serialize()` will bind to `Kiralayan kisi`, and this just adds `..&aracid=someValue` to the form data so it will bind to the additional parameter

Comment: Then could you tell me what will happaned if ViewModel have `aracid` property and controller have same extra parameter `aracid`?

Comment: Hmm, I've never tested that :), but I would guess only one would be bound (the `DefaultModelBinder` ignores subsequent `name/value` pairs with the same name unless the property is `IEnumerable`) but I'm not sure. Something to test tomorrow. I'll let you know.

Comment: @teo van kot: If the name occurs in the model and a parameter, it will map to *both* the model property and the extra parameter. My own answer updated to include this little factoid.

Answer (score 1):

MVC will map the object for you, so you might as well skip the extract nesting of the form within the object.

### Notes:

- If `aracid` is also a property in the model, it will map to *both* the property *and* the extra parameter.
- Using push on the `serialise()` collection is more maintainable than the alternative of concatenating strings before the `serialize()` call.

**e.g.**

```
 var Kiralayan = $("#RentForm").serialize();            
 // Add the extra non-form parameter
 Kiralayan.push({name: 'aracid', value: P.AracID});
```

**Full example:**

```
    function Kaydet() {
        var Kiralayan = $("#RentForm").serialize();            
        // Add the extra non-form parameter
        Kiralayan.push({name: 'aracid', value: P.AracID});         
        console.log(params);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Save","AracKirala")',
            data: Kiralayan,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != "OK") {
                    alert("Kayıt yapılamadı.");
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("RentForm").reset();
                    alert("Kayıt başarıyla gerçekleştirildi.");
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                    Ara();
                }

            }
        });
```