# Sending serialized form to controller plus some other data

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have got a form that I can successfully send to my controller action:

```
this.submitForm = function (e) {
    var formData = $("#FinalizeForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
        data: formData
    });
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyMethod(SomeModel model)
```

And works fine. However, I want to send additional data along with the form's, something like:

```
var test = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: '40',
    nationality: 'Portuguese'
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
    data: {
        model: formData,
        test: test
    }
});
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyMethod(SomeModel model, AnotherModel test)
```

But this way, the `model` variable comes null and the `test` one comes populated. Why is this? Why did the model come populated before and now doesn't?

I tested sending it alone but in a different way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
    data: {
        model: formData
    }
});
```

But `model` still comes as null.

Comment: One option shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268). Another option is to use `FormData` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **data:**
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array

Documentation on [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject): (emphasis mine)

> The PlainObject type is a JavaScript object containing **zero or more key-value pairs**. The plain object is, in other words, an Object object. It is designated "plain" in jQuery documentation to distinguish it from other kinds of JavaScript objects: for example, null, user-defined arrays, and host objects such as document, all of which have a typeof value of "object." The jQuery.isPlainObject() method identifies whether the passed argument is a plain object or not.

Your `data` doesn't qualify as either `PlainObject`, `String` or `Array`.

Comment: Alright, now I know why it doesn't work, thanks! I still need to find out how to send everything I need

Comment: @chiapa Wouldn't [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29293681/3410196) suggested by Stephen work?

Comment: It won't because the added data I want to send isn't from inputs. Anyway, I think I found a workaround by adding plain text to the serialized form variable - I am working on it and post it if it's any good. Thanks

Comment: @chiapa, Read both the links I gave you in my comment to your question again. Both methods allow you to serialize your form and add additional data that is not part of the form or from an input. Using `FormData` is easiest you do it by the code shown in the last paragraph/code snippet of the answer