# Calling my controller with multiple parameters including a serialized form

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How do I call my controller's action method with 3 parameters and a serialized form?

Here is what I have but the 'SearchCriteria sc' parameter is null.

```
public JsonResult CreateDynamicCollection(int[] arrIds, string collectionName, int parentCollectionId, SearchCriteria sc)
{
  // sc is null
}

public class SearchCriteria
{

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    // other fields here left out 
}
```

```js
 var model = {};
 model.arrIds = arrIds;
 model.parentCollectionId = parentId;
 model.collectionName = $createCollectionName.val();
 var form = $('#formAdvSearch')[0];
 model.form = $(form).serialize();

 $.post(controller, model, function(response) {
     if (response.error == false) {
       //do some stuff
     }
   })
   .fail(function() {

   })
   .always(function() {

   });
```

Comment: What you're doing won't work.  You can't send a model with a serialized property.

Comment: it works if that's all I send with no other parameters!!!!

Comment: If your going to use `.serialize()`, then you need to add the other values using the `$.param()` method. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268) for an example.

Comment: can I use serializeArray() and then push the additional values into the array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did,

I passed in a a more complex serialzed data structure.

```js
var form = $('#formAdvSearch')[0];
var serializedForm = $(form).serializeArray();
serializedForm.push({
  name: 'arrIds',
  value: arrIds
});
serializedForm.push({
  name: 'parentCollectionId',
  value: parentId
});
serializedForm.push({
  name: 'collectionName',
  value: $createCollectionName.val()
});
model = serializedForm;
```

Then I made my new object accepting the model inherit the old object and the new items were placed in the new obj