# how to send array brackets in json nested objects in web api controller

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am sending data to a rest API of a travel portal. According to their documentation, the json data must be in the following format

```
{
    "EndUserIp": "192.168.10.10",
    "TokenId": "ac2751e9-4cc3-406f-b678-c947e4f57a00",
    "AdultCount": "1",
    "ChildCount": "0",
    "InfantCount": "0",
    "DirectFlight": "false",
    "OneStopFlight": "false",
    "JourneyType": "1",
    "PreferredAirlines": null,
    "Segments": [
    {
        "Origin": "DEL",
        "Destination": "BOM",
        "FlightCabinClass": "1",
        "PreferredDepartureTime": "2015-11-06T00: 00: 00",
        "PreferredArrivalTime": "2015-11-06T00: 00: 00"
    }],
    "Sources": [
        "6E"
    ]
}
```

My models are

```
public class otherType
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public FlightCabinClass FlightCabinClass { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime? PreferredDepartureTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime PreferredArrivalTime { get; set; }
}

public class SearchForFlight
{
    public SearchForFlight()
    {
        JourneyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        FlightCabinClassList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Segments = new otherType();
    }
    public string EndUserIp { get; set; }
    public string TokenId { get; set; }
    public int AdultCount { get; set; }
    public int ChildCount { get; set; }
    public int InfantCount { get; set; }
    public bool DirectFlight { get; set; }
    public bool OneStopFlight { get; set; }
    public JourneyType JourneyType { get; set; }
    public string PreferedLines { get; set; }
    public otherType Segments { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlightCabinClassList { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JourneyList { get; set; }
    public string Sources { get; set; }
}
```

The following code populates my model correctly, but if I include the square brackets, binding fails.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {                 
        $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            var sof = {
                AdultCount: $("#AdultCount").val(),
                JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),
                PreferredAirlines: null,
                Segments:
                {
                    Origin: $("#Segments_Origin").val(),
                    Destination: $("#Segments_Destination").val(),
                    FlightCabinClass: $("#FlightCabinClass").val(),
                    PreferredDepartureTime: $("#Segments_PreferredDepartureTime").val(),
                    PreferredArrivalTime: $("#Segments_PreferredArrivalTime").val(),
                }
            };
```

Controller

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SearchFlight([FromBody]SearchForFlight sof)
{
    string url = "http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/Search/";
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

How do I generate the correct format and bind to the model?

Comment: Based on the model in your link, `Segments` is an object (typeof `otherType`) not a collection of objects) so you cannot generate a collection using `[ ... ]`. What to you mean the _according to documentation_? Are you posting to an API that requires the property `Segments` to be a collection? (in which case you need to change your model)

Comment: According to documents means sample request/response provided by travel portal to talk to their rest api. The sample Request is here: http://pastebin.com/2n7ZjsBE Now how should i modify my model sir?? @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to edit your question with that information, plus the model (links to code are not acceptable). But basically your property needs to be `public IEnumerable<otherType> Segments { get; set; }` and use the code in your first snippet. Of course this would all be far easier if you just used `$('form').serialize();` rather than manually building your object.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it a bit clearer what your wanting to do. I'll add an answer in about 30 min :)

Comment: Edited my ques, changed property to public IEnumerable<otherType> Segments { get; set; } now, in constructor of model any change needed?? and what would be here @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Segments., htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) and where to use $('form').serialize();

Comment: Will add the details in the answer - can I assume you only want to edit one `Segment` object?

Comment: i am not able to post any object's in Segment and my view page started complaining so i just asked only for one label just provide the answer sir i will try to use accordingingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API format means the the `Segments` property must be a collection of `otherType` (your model only has a single object). In addition the `Sources` property is also a collection of `string`.

Change you model to

```
public class SearchForFlight
{
    public SearchForFlight()
    {
        Segments = new List<otherType>();
        Sources = new List<string>();
    }
    ....
    public string PreferedLines { get; set; }
    public List<otherType> Segments { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlightCabinClassList { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JourneyList { get; set; }
    public List<string> Sources { get; set; }
}
```

and then assuming your only wanting to edit one `Segments` and one `Sources`, then in the GET method, add one object to each collection

```
SearchForFlight model = new SearchForFlight();
model.Segments.Add(new otherType());
model.Sources.Add(string.Empty);
....
return View(model);
```

and in the view, use `for` loops to generate the html for the collections

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Segments.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Segments[i].Origin)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Segments[i].Origin)
    @Html.ValidationMesageFor(m => m.Segments[i].Origin)
    .... // other properties of otherType
}
```

Note that this will generate `id` attributes such as `id="Segments_0__Origin"` so your script would need to be

```
Segments:
{
    Origin: $("#Segments_0__Origin").val(),
    Destination: $("#Segments_0__Destination").val(),
    ....
```

however there is no need to generate you javascript object manually, and your ajax can be simply

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    ....
```

and do not set the `contentType` option so it uses the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: model.Segments.Add(new otherType()); problem at this line 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<xx.Models.OtherType>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type Error

Comment: Its `public List<otherType> Segments { get; set; }` (not `IEnumerable<otherType>`)

Comment: Only value of FlightCabinClass which is a dropdown is correct in posted data to web api controller but all other properties are still null @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Using which option - `.serialize()` or `Origin: $("#Segments_0__Origin").val(),`? If its not binding, its because your view is wrong or your using the wrong jquery selectors (check the actual `id` attributes of the elements)

Comment: but one problem still, some properties for like EndUserIp I have to send default value 192.168.10.10 So, is it possible with $('form').serialize()

Comment: Yes, if you include a hidden input for the property - `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EndUserIp)` and in the GET method, set the value before you pass the model to the view - `model.EndUserIp = "192.168.10.10";`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `param` method as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268)

Comment: what would be syntax for sources just want to add single string "6E" and on view page tried this  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Sources.Count; i++)
                       {
                           <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Sources)
                               </div>
                       }

Comment: `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Sources.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Sources[i]) }`

Comment: and in model is it correct to add like this ?  model.Sources.Add("6E");