# How to send model binded to view from ajax call on button click to controller action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my ajax call:

```
$('#addNominationForm').on("submit", function (e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddNomination", "Nomination")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ model: model, submit: "submit" }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            swal({
                title: "Nominated Successfully",
                showCancelButton: false,
                confirmButtonColor: "#88a364",
                confirmButtonText: "Ok"
            },
            function () {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")';
                }
            });
        },
        Error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error" + xhr.responseText)
        }
    });
});
```

This is action:

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomeAuthorize(AllowedRole = "Manager")]
public ActionResult AddNomination(NominationViewModel model, string submit)
{
    //business logic in action
}
```

But here when ajax call is done, in action model contains null. How can I do it?Or is there any other way to send model on view using ajax call on normal button click?

Comment: Show how you generate the javascript variable for `model` (if its `null` then you have not generated it correctly)

Comment: var model = $('#addNominationForm').serialize()

Comment: That will not work. If your serializing your form, then you need to add the additional value to it as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268) and you need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and not use `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

Dont stringify your data:

```
data: { model: model, submit: "submit" }
```

POST has a body that is JSON (in this case)

GET can get data from the querystring so thats where you need stringify

Comment: I forget to assign value to model here..What wud be stored in 'model' variable?

Comment: The NominationViewModel in json form