# Ajax serialize with extra data MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I use a webgid so to display records that have to do with the user. I load this webgrid in a partilal view after the user clicks on an ajax actionlink.

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "AddUserElements", "Users", new { username = item.UserName }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "add_research"}, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-link" })
```

In this webgrid I have a delete action. When I click the delete a modal appears so to ask for verification. I click on yes and the record is being deleted but the webgrid in the partial view doesn't being refreshed. To update the partial view I use in my ajax code

```
  $("#add_research").load('/Users/AddUserElements');
```

I tried to pass the username with serialize to controller but no lack

My ajax code

```
       $(function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
       $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
       $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        bindForm(this);
    });
    return false;
});
});

 function bindForm(dialog) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    $('#progress').show();
     var data = $(this).serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'username': '@Model.UserName' }, true);

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: "POST",

        data: data,

        cache: false,

        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {

                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#progress').hide();

              $("#add_research").load('/Users/AddUserElements');


            } else {
                $('#progress').hide();
                $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                bindForm();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
 }
```

My controller

```
 public ActionResult AddUserElements(string username)
```

Any idea?
thank you

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I try to delete a record from a webgrid. I tried your code but when I delete the record the web grid returns empty. It should return with the corresponding records about the user.  My string username returns empty. In my url I have: `url: this.action,` . If I use `'@Url.Action("User","AddUser")',`. it doesnt work at all.

Comment: That means that `Model.UserName` is `null`

Comment: When I first run the code so to fill the webgrid the username is not null. It brings the records for the user normally. thank you

Comment: You have not given enough information for anyone to even guess what you might be doing wrong

Comment: I update my question. I dont know if is more clear now. thank you

Comment: Anything in the browsers console? (F12)

Comment: Clear as mud. Where do you use `data: $(this).serialize()`? (you have not shown any ajax code). And is that in the partial view or main view? As previously stated, it means `Model.UserName` and to test it, in the same view that your `data: $(this).serialize()` code is add `<div>Name : @Model.UserName</div>` and see the results

Comment: When I run the code the UserName returns ok but when I delete the record then it returns null. The username is being pass to controller via tha ajax actionlink

Comment: In your javascript or jquery code of delete row button..you can first empty the target div like this `$('#add_research').html('')` . Then you can again fill it up with the html generated from the ajax request like this `$('#add_research').html('Your view Html')`;

Comment: For that I actually use the ` $("#add_research").load('/Users/AddUserElements');` because I need to reload  partial view so to show the records. I see the headers of the webgrid but not data. I need to re fill the `username` variable correctly.