# passing parameter in ajax gets null value

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm calling an action controller using ajax but the parameter I'm passing with the `data` attribute is always null when the action controller receives it...
What could be happening in here?

JQuery function:

```
function PostOrder()
{      
    var id = $(".aslink").data("customerid");
    var url = $("#btnAddOrderPost").data("url_add_order");       
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify( { orderVM: $("#frmCreatePV").serialize()}),
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () {
            alert("it was inserted");
        }
    })
}
```

Action controller:

```
[HttpPost]
   // [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreatePV(OrderVM orderVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<string> top = new List<string>();
            decimal tempPrice = 0M;
            for (int i = 0; i < orderVM.Toppings.Count; i++)
            {
                if (orderVM.Toppings[i].IsSelected == true)
                {
                    top.Add(orderVM.Toppings[i].SpecificTopping);
                    tempPrice += orderVM.Toppings[i].Price;
                }
            }
            Order order = new Order
            {                 
                Toppings = top,
                TotalPrice = tempPrice
            };
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }            
        return View(orderVM);
    }
```

This is the OrderVM ViewModel I'm using a parameter of this type:

```
public class OrderVM
{           
    public virtual List<ToppingVM> Toppings { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the form which is contained inside a Partial View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @id="frmCreatePV"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @{
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Toppings.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Toppings[i].SpecificTopping)                       
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Toppings[i].IsSelected, htmlAttributes: new { data_price = Model.Toppings[i].Price, @id = "chbkPrice" })                      
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Toppings[i].Price)
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Toppings[i].IsSelected , Model.Toppings[i].SpecificTopping)                        
                        <p>Price: @Model.Toppings[i].Price</p>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Add order" id="btnAddOrderPost" class="btn btn-primary"
                       data-url_add_order="@Url.Action("CreatePV", "Orders")" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                }
```

**UPDATE**

Finally this is how the Action Controller stayed:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult CreatePV(OrderVM orderVM)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["License"]);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<string> top = new List<string>();
            decimal tempPrice = 0M;
            for (int i = 0; i < orderVM.Toppings.Count; i++)
            {
                if (orderVM.Toppings[i].IsSelected == true)
                {
                    top.Add(orderVM.Toppings[i].SpecificTopping);
                    tempPrice += orderVM.Toppings[i].Price;
                }
            }
            Order order = new Order
            {
                Customer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.LicenseNumber == id).First(),
                LicenseNumber = id,
                Toppings = top,
                TotalPrice = tempPrice
            };
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success= true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet});
        }           
        return Json(new { success = false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet});
    }
```

And the JQuery function, note that I made use of serializeArray() to add an element to the data that was not bound to the html form :

```
function PostOrder()
{
    var orderVM = {};   
    id = $(".aslink").data("customerid");
    alert($("#btnGetOrderAdd").data("customerid"));
    var url = $("#btnAddOrderPost").data("url_add_order");
    var datavar = $("#frmCreatePV").serializeArray();
    datavar.push({name: "LicenseNumber" ,value : id})  
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: url,       
        data: datavar,
        datatype: "json",      
        success: function () {
            alert("it was inserted");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Just try to remove contentType. and try to debug using console, that it really comes on jquery before passing to ajax

Comment: @Loading.. I removed contentType and now is working, why? You can post an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Check my answer, I've answer your why there.

Comment: Removing the `contentType` option cannot possibly work unless you also change the `data` option to `data: $("#frmCreatePV").serialize(),` and also removed `datatype: "json",` (and changed it to `dataType: "html"`). No idea why you have accepted an incorrect answer which appears to be about PHP.  And `return RedirectToAction("Index");` cannot possibly work - you making an ajax call and ajax calls never redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right about the Redirect, I'm working on that Action Controller I just was testing the parameter(orderVM) and why it was null, I wasn't working yet in the content of the Action Controller, I selected it as an answer because once I removed the contentType it worked. If you tell me that only removing the contentType is not enough I believe you, probably I did something else, I'll make an update in my question showing my final Action Controller and JQuery function, if you have any suggestion I will take it in count like I always do

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why should I change datatype:"json" to datatype:"html"?

Comment: Because your code before your edit was returning a view (html) not json. But now that your returning a `JsonResult`, then you can leave it as `datatype:"json"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks Stephen, I always learn more with your suggestions :)

Comment: Note also you should avoid `.serializeArray()` (it will not work correctly if you have used `CheckBoxFor()` in your view). Better to use `.serialize()` and if you want to add other values you can use `$.param()` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268) for an example) or you could simply have added a hidden input for `LicenseNumber` so it would be serialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `contentType` will work for you.

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, which is the default.

When using `contentType: 'application/json'` you will not be able to rely on $_POST being populated.  $_POST is only populated for form-encoded content types.

In that case, you can access the PHP raw data.

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$object = json_encode($input);
```

Hope this helps you :)