# How to post a form as a View Model object, along with other parameters to the controller in MVC?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in controller as:

```
public int Edit(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
     // code to edit
}
```

And I am posting a form as:

```
$.post("/MyController/Edit", $("#form").serialize()).then(
  function () {
    $("#dialog1").dialog("close");
    $("#list-grid").trigger('reloadGrid');
});
```

This works fine. I get the parameter in the  same format as `MyViewModel` .

However, I need to pass one more parameter to the action. So I have changed the controller to:

```
public int Edit(MyViewModel viewModel, string oldValue)
{
      // code to edit
}
```

Now, I tried following way to pass the `viewModel` along with the `oldValue` to the action using an ajax call:

```
var object = $("#form").serialize();
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "MyController")',
        type: "POST",            
        contentType:                            // please see below            
        data: { viewModel: object, oldValue: oldVal},
        dataType:                               // please see below
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (response) {
                alert("Successfully updated!");
               }
});
```

Although I am able to get the value of `oldValue`, the `viewModel` comes as `null`, although it is exactly the same as that sent in the `$.post(...)` , when examined in the console.

If I specify the `contentType` as any of:

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` or,

`application/json; charset=utf-8` or,

`application/json`

the call fails.

I have tried without specifying the `dataType`, and also by specifying it as a `json`, but in vain.

Creating a custom class for de-serializing the `json` sent is not doable.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try this: `data: JSON.stringify({ viewModel: object, oldValue: oldVal})`

Comment: You can use `$.param()` to add additional name/value pairs to the serialized object - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268)

Comment: I instead used `.serializeArray()` and added a new field as well. It is a better option if you need to edit some values in the serialized form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that value of `oldVal` is not NULL. You can try this:

```
var object = $("#form").serialize();
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "MyController")',
        type: "POST",            
        contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8                           // please see below            
        data: JSON.stringify{ viewModel: object, oldValue: oldVal},
        success: function (response) {
                alert("Successfully updated!");
               }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType: "JSON",` before `data: { viewModel: object, oldValue: oldVal}`