# Passing a model to controller via ajax (results are null/jumbled up)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I asked a question regarding this problem. I have tried all the solutions given but to no avail. I think the problem I'm having with this is that I am not setting the parameter's data type properly?

What I am trying to do here is to receive a model from a controller and when another action happens, I will pass back that model, along with pre-inserted values, to the controller. (I don't wanna make several calls to the server).

Is there any way at all I can receive the data as it is? That is if I pass my model to the controller, the controller will receive the data as a whole and not a string.

My codes are below:

**ViewFacilities.html (View)**

```
@using Tp.Cis.Tprbs
@model Tp.Cis.Tprbs.Models.ViewFacilitiesModel

<form id="my-hidden-form">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.facilityTypeId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ftm)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.bdList)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.currentTerms)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.openHours)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.firstDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.lastDate)
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getTimeSlots(date, facilityid) {
                var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("RetrieveTimeslots", "Booking")",
                    data: {
                        'chosenDate': date.toISOString(),
                        'facilityid': document.getElementById('selectFacilities').value,
                        'vfmx': $("#my-hidden-form").serialize(),
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('data here', data);
                    }
                });
</script>
```

**ViewFacilitiesModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tp.Cis.Tprbs.Models
{
    public class ViewFacilitiesModel
    {
        public Array disabledDates { get; set; }
        public string maxDate { get; set; }
        public List<TimeSlotsModel> allSlots { get; set; }
        public int facilityTypeId { get; set; }
        public FacilityTypeModel ftm { get; set; }
        public List<BlockOutDateModel> bdList { get; set; }
        public List<AcademicCalendarModel> currentTerms { get; set; }
        public List<OpeningHourModel> openHours { get; set; }
        public DateTime firstDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controllers**

```
public virtual ActionResult ViewFacilities(string facilitytype, int facilitytypeid){

            ViewFacilitiesModel vfm = new ViewFacilitiesModel();
            vfm.disabledDates = listOfFullBlockDates.ToArray();
            vfm.maxDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            vfm.facilityTypeId = facilitytypeid;
            vfm.ftm = ftm;
            vfm.bdList = bdList;
            vfm.currentTerms = currentTerms;
            vfm.openHours = openHours;
            vfm.firstDate = dtNow.Date;
            vfm.lastDate = endDate;


            var tempFacility = facilitytype;
            return View(vfm);
}

public ActionResult RetrieveTimeslots(DateTime chosenDate, int facilityid, string vfmx){
    //receive ajax data here
}
```

The data that I get in the controller when I try to send my model over, with a string data type for the controller's parameter is:

*facilityTypeId=2&ftm=Tp.Cis.Tprbs.Models.FacilityTypeModel&bdList=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BTp.Cis.Tprbs.Models.BlockOutDateModel%5D&currentTerms=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BTp.Cis.Tprbs.Models.AcademicCalendarModel%5D&openHours=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BTp.Cis.Tprbs.Models.OpeningHourModel%5D&firstDate=10%2F02%2F2017+00%3A00%3A00&lastDate=19%2F02%2F2017+18%3A21%3A15*

When I tried changing the data type to the Model class instead, I get a null:

```
public ActionResult RetrieveTimeslots(DateTime chosenDate, int facilityid, ViewFacilitiesModel vfmx){
        //receive ajax data here
    }
```

Any help would be great

Comment: You have multiple issues. First `bdList` and `currentTerms` and `openHours` are collections of complex objects. You cannot use a hidden input for a collection or complex object (look at the html your generating to understand why that would never bind.

Comment: But why in the world would you send all that data to the client and then send it back again unchanged? And since you have a view model, why does that not include properties for `chosenDate` and `facilityid`?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke chosenDate and facilityid are not the problem. Those values are retrieved from the client. And the reason of me passing unchanged values is because I have to use those values in the view controller and the other controller, which requires calls to the server. I just dont wanna make multiple calls.

Comment: Regarding the complex objects, I guess that would explain a lot. Say if I were to remove them and keep the simple ones. What would the parameter's data type be? Would it be the model?

Comment: I know they are not a problem! Pass just the ID of the object to the controller and get the data again in the server (calling a database is blindingly fast assuming your have set it up right. Sending data to the client and then back again across the wire is not. And a malicious user can easily modify it without you knowing)

Comment: But there are other issues with the way you construct the data anyway - you serialize the model, so to include the extra properties you need to use `.param()` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268), although its not relevant because you should not be sending the model.

Comment: I did not think of security. Thanks for the heads up! I'll try simplifying my model then.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here but your main issue seems to be that you are attempting to serialise your complex types (`currentTerms` for example) into simple hidden fields.  You can't do that (it would be great if things were that easy!) - hence you are getting the string representation of the type when you post the data back to the server (e.g `Tp.Cis.Tprbs.Models.FacilityTypeModel`).

I'd do a few things:

Change the signature of your post action to just accept a view model

```
public ActionResult RetrieveTimeslots(ViewFacilitiesModel viewModel) { .. }
```

The framework is really good at tying JSON data posted to the server to strongly typed models.

If you must have the lists of objects preserved, then I think you've got three options:

1. send some JSON to the client and handle stringifying it with JavaScript
2. come up with a convoluted way of rendering hidden elements for each item in the list
3. simplify your view model, or even break it down in to smaller chunks so that you're just rendering simple types

Personally, I'd go down the JS route, but whatever way you choose you need to "manage" the lists/complex types in such a way that only primitive values are rendered in you HTML.

Comment: I think I'll simplify the model. So in regards to sending the model to the controller, do I do the same way i.e. serialize? Or can I just do @HTML.URL("RetrieveTimeslots", "Booking", @Model)?

Comment: @AdamLoh - The easiest way is to serialise the form.  Note - the form inputs need to have names that match the properties on the ViewModel (case sensitive)