# Cannot append or post CKEditor value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor in an ASP.NET MVC application and I cannot append or post the **updated** value of the textarea as shown below:

```
<textarea name="Description" id="Description" rows="10" cols="80">
    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
</textarea>

<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('Description',
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/....',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/....'
});
</script>


function insert(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var desc = CKEDITOR.instances['Description'].getData(); //I obtain the updated text at this line
    var formdata = $('#frmCreate').serialize(); 

    formdata.append("Description", desc); //!!! This is not working !!!  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Insert", "Blog")',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: formdata,

        success: function (response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
};
```

I can pass the initial value of the textarea (DEscription property of teh model), but after making any change the data still keep the initial value. Any idea about how to pass the Description field to the Controller???

Comment: You could always use `$('#Description').val(data);` and then `var formdata = $('#frmCreate').serialize();`

Comment: And as a side note, you have `dataType: "json",` but seem to be returning `html` which would throw an exception.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You rock as everytime, many thanks!.. Just some point that I need to be clarified >>> **1)** In that case can I use **$('#property').val(dataValue);** in order to append dataValue to my property instead of append method??? **2)** I use **[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]** in order to fix internal server error and worked. However, when trying "html" or "text" for dataType, the problem did not solved. Any idea?

Comment: You have not shown the controller method so a bit hard to coment on item 3. For item 2, its better to use `[AllowHtml]` attribute on your `Description` property.

Comment: For item 1, I'm not familiar with CKEDITOR so not sure why it does not automatically update the value of the input, but note that if you want to 'append' something to the output of `.serialize()` then you can use `$.param` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268). However in you case that would not work since only the first value of `Description` in the output will be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Many thanks for your good explanations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor auto-updates `<textarea>` when the form is submitted in the traditional way (classic submit). If you are using Ajax, you need to update the `<textarea>` manually with https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement.

See also the [CKEditor in Ajax Applications](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/saveajax.html) sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot... It is a shortcut for updating CKEditor :)